# What font is used in the Heritage Publishing logo from the sixties?

Tags: font-identification

I am trying recreate this logo’s type and having a problem finding the font. This logo was designed in the early sixties.

[image: Heritage Publishing logo]

Comment: I don't think it's a font. It's a custom made.

Answer (score 3):

Given the era and the slight imperfections between similar letters (such as the 'i') this does not appear to be a font but hand lettering.

Comment: I agree, there are tiny differences on the dots of the i, the two lowercase e and g are slightly different and the loops of the blh seem to have thickened from the ink.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will like some another script with some similarities...

i.e. [Anglia Script](http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Script/19137/Anglia_Script):

[image]

Comment: Not for recreating a particular logo, though.

Comment: @DA01 If the topic starter expands the characters in Illustrator, the logo in question can be easily reproduced to 100% match... IMHO

Comment: If the goal is to reproduce (which I assume is the goal) it'd make more sense to redraw based on the original--rather than modifying a different typeface to get to that same end result. There's enough hand-made quirks in the original that I'd think one would want to keep them. Of course, it's impossible for us to say without knowing the details of the project.